# How to strongly type zero argument primitives

Tags: python, strong-typing, genetic-programming, deap

I'm trying to write a genetic program in Python using DEAP and have several zero argument functions as terminals. I want to be able to combine them using, for example, an if_then_else primitive but this primitive keeps trying to call my other int type terminals. I want to strongly type the pset to avoid this but DEAP won't allow me to use None type arguments when adding strongly typed primitives, what can I do?

This is the code defining the pset I have so far

```
def progn(*args):
    for arg in args:
        arg()

def prog2(out1, out2): 
    return partial(progn,out1,out2)

def prog3(out1, out2, out3):     
    return partial(progn,out1,out2,out3)

def if_then_else(condition, out1, out2):
    out1() if condition() else out2()   

pset = gp.PrimitiveSetTyped("main", [None, int, bool], None)

pset.addPrimitive(if_wall_ahead, [None, None], None)
pset.addPrimitive(prog2, [None, None], None)
pset.addPrimitive(prog3, [None, None, None], None)
pset.addPrimitive(compare, [int,int], bool)
pset.addPrimitive(operator.and_, [bool, bool], bool)
pset.addPrimitive(operator.or_, [bool, bool], bool)
pset.addPrimitive(operator.not_, [bool], bool)

pset.addTerminal(player.changeDirectionRight, None)
pset.addTerminal(player.changeDirectionUp, None)
pset.addTerminal(player.changeDirectionLeft, None)
pset.addTerminal(player.changeDirectionDown, None)
pset.addTerminal(player.h_target_distance, int)
pset.addTerminal(player.v_target_distance, int)
pset.addEphemeralConstant("rand", random.randint(0,20), int)
```

Comment: Show us the code you have so far.

Comment: Just put the pset code in the body

Answer (score 1):

You can create a dummy class to represent your boolean types, because bool and int are the "same types".

One of the DEAP authors suggest a solution like that:

```
class Bool(object): pass
pset.addPrimitive(xxxx, [yyy, yyy], Bool)
```

You can read a [discussion about that on github](https://github.com/DEAP/deap/pull/106#issuecomment-158790599), maybe this can be helpuful.